# Locate sparse faces

Tags: faces

I noticed that the mesh I'm working on has some 'disperse' faces I noticed a couple and removed them but I think they can be many more and I need to avoid that... how can I select them?
The object is too complex to select all the faces manually (at least using the basic methods I know) and then use 'select -> inverse' to get all the remaining.

Comment: You could try (in Face Select mode) to use the Select > Select All By Trait > Loose Geometry?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "sparse", "disperse"?  Maybe some pics demonstrating what those mean to you.

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your object, got to edit mode and select a vertex of your "main" mesh. Then do this: > select linked

[image]

Result:

[image]

If you then invert your selections (<kbd>CTRL-I</kbd>) you got all "dispersed" selected.

[image]

Comment: I tried this but probably because of topology issues (in this mesh) almost no vertex where selected using this approach.

Comment: hint: next time provide your blend file, so we can help with your mesh.